# Xcode 4 C++ header file with relative path to another header

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, xcode4

I'm using a library with an include structure where the .h files are all in a single directory. These .h files contains a single line, a `#include` directive which points to the 'real' header file in specific source folder locations. The `#include` path in these files is relative.

So, here's an example. The directory structure is:

```
/project
     /sources 
         <my .cpp files>
         <my .cpp files>
         ...
     /include
         /component
             foo1.h
             foo2.h
     /platformA/something/foo1.h
     /platformB/somethingelse/foo2.h
```

/include/component/foo1.h contains a single line of code:
`#include "../platformA/something/foo1.h"`

/include/component/foo2.h contains the single line of code `#include "../platformB/somethingelse/foo2.h"`

In my sources, I simply have:
`#include "component/foo1.h"`

The header search path for my project points to `/include`

Now, Xcode 4 is able to find `component/foo1.h` in `/include`, but it's unable to follow the relative include path within those headers and find the 'real' foo1.h in the `/platformA/something' directory, and so on.

I suspect it's because the include paths in the top-level foo1.h file is relative to its location, but Xcode might be treating it as relative to some other location (project root or something)? FWIW, Visual Studio has no problems with an identical configuration.

What can I do to remedy this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your directory structure it seems that the directories `platformA` and `platformB` are placed outside the include folder. There are two possible solutions to this:

Solution A

> Move these
>   to `include` folder.

Solution B

> Add `project/platformA` and
>   `project/platformB` to the
>   `directories where include files
>   should be looked for` in project
>   settings.

Comment: I realized that in my attempt to simplify I had left out a few things. I updated the example to be more real. In my sources, I would like to `#include "component/foo1.h"`, so your suggestion of moving stuff into the include folder won't really work (it would have in my incorrectly simplified example - sorry about that).

Comment: Then you can check the second solution I have proposed.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use relative paths. Seriously, it's implementation-defined behavior how they work, so different compilers/environments/platforms will behave differently, and in your case, Xcode is almost certainly invoking GCC or clang in some sort of "build" directory, which may or may not be a sibling to your sources directory.

It's not worth the headache.

Put `platformA` and `platformB` in `include`, or add another directory (say, `platform-include`) put them in there, and add that directory to your include path.

Comment: Thanks, but that's not much help sadly. I share this code across multiple platform/build systems and this isn't source I control. I'd like to try and get this to work before I make life worse for me than it already is.

Comment: @psychotik: Nevermind, that doesn't actually match what you were saying, sorry.