# Xcode header search path not working for an include relative to another header

Tags: xcode, header-files

I have a file in my project that is `#including` a header file

`#import "core.hpp"`

In my header search paths, I put this path:

`./OpenCV2.4.9/OSX/include   recursive`

And this works, Xcode can find `core.hpp` even though I don't reference it in my project.

`core.hpp`'s full path is: `./OpenCV2.4.9/OSX/include/opencv2/core/core.hpp`

The problem is that inside of `core.hpp`, there is another `#include`

`#include "opencv2/core/types_c.h"`

Xcode cannot find this header.

I have played with every build setting that I could find, to no avail.

It's odd because we have this working in another one of our projects, but in this new test project I'm making, I can't seem to get it to work even with all of the build settings matching (As far as I can tell)

This is the closest SO question I could find related to mine:
[XCode 4 C++ header file with relative path to another header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6303267/xcode-4-c-header-file-with-relative-path-to-another-header)

But the problem is that I cannot change `#include "opencv2/core/types_c.h"`, because it's not my header

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured it out.
I changed the header search path to

> ./OpenCV2.4.9/OSX

from

> ./OpenCV2.4.9/OSX/include

I found this by modifying the OpenCV header, and found that while
`#include "opencv2/core/types_c.h"` didn't work;
if I just did `#include "types_c.h"` it would work, and further, `#include "core/types_c.h"` also worked

And because I didn't actually want to modify the OpenCV headers,
I found that if I just removed the last piece of the header search path, `include`, Xcode was finally happy